# Firebase Hosting: Function not working with ServerMiddleware (Vue/ Nuxt)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting

I am building a project that utilises ServerMiddleware to render some pages client side only (I can't find another way of getting this working well without ServerMiddleware. Problems on refreshing pages and so on...)

**The problem:** Unfortunately every time I try and deploy to my Firebase  Function through 'firebase deploy' I get an error:

> Error: Cannot find module '~/serverMiddleware/selectiveSSR.js'

The function builds OK if I exclude the following line. Nuxt/ Vue is not including **~/serverMiddleware/** as part of its build as far as I can see.

Here is the code in nuxt.config.js to reference my serverMiddleware:

```
serverMiddleware: ['~/serverMiddleware/selectiveSSR.js']
```

Adding either the directory or path (as above) to the file itself within Build in nuxt.config.js does not help either. Maybe I am doing it wrong?

Everything works perfectly when testing (Not building) locally.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this please?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understood correctly, the following line didn't help as well right? serverMiddleware: ['~/serverMiddleware']

Comment: It didn't. I found a solution, see below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so for anyone else who hits this, here is how I got around it.

Firstly, I don't know if this is the fault of Firebase Hosting or Nuxt (I would guess Nuxt but I stand to be corrected), but here is what to do....

1) Remove any reference to ServerMiddleware from **nuxt.config.js**

2) Add the following to **nuxt.config.js**

```
modules: [
    '~/local-modules/your-module-name'
  ],
```

3) Create directory **~/local-modules/your-module-name** in your project root

4) In the new directory, create a package.json:

```
{
    "name": "your-module-name",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  }
```

and index.js - key thing, `this.addServerMiddleware` allows you to call middleware server-side

```
module.exports = function(moduleOptions) {
  this.addServerMiddleware('~/serverMiddleware/')
}
```

5) Create directory **~/serverMiddleware**

6) Add your middleware function to index.js in the new directory:

```
export default function(req, res, next) {
 // YOUR CODE
  next() // Always end with next()!
}
```

7) Update **package.json** with your new local module under "dependencies":

```
    "your-module-name": "file:./local-modules/your-module-name"
```

Don't forget you need to do this within the functions directory too or Firebase will complain it can't find your new module

Comment: That's great! Please consider accepting your own answer so the community can find this solution when facing a similar problem :)

Comment: It didn't work for me unfortunatelly. Still the same error. `Cannot resolve "~/serverMiddleware/" from "workspace/serverMiddleware/"`.