# Firebase "cant' resolve" server middleware handler in nuxtjs project ("Can't resolve "~/graphql/index.js" from "/workspace/graphql/index.js")

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I am trying to deploy `nuxtjs` app as cloud function on Firebase following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aTvdnqY3ek). I am able to deploy everything (functions and hosting). However, when I try to open the page browser displays `Error: could not handle the request`.

In the function logs I see the following error: `FATAL  Cannot resolve "~/graphql/index.js" from "/workspace/graphql/index.js"`.

The path that fails to be resolved is specified in `nuxt.config.js` in serverMiddleware:

```
 serverMiddleware: [{ path: '/graphql', handler: '~/graphql/index.js' }],
```

I tried using `./` instead of `~/` but it changes nothing. I also tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536536/firebase-hosting-function-not-working-with-servermiddleware-vue-nuxt), but it also makes no change, same error is thrown. Obviously dev server runs correctly.

Although the middleware is a graphql one I don't think it's a graphql problem, so no graphql tag at the moment.

Does anyone know how to set up a nuxt server middleware so that Firebase can resolve it?

Comment: Hey! I'm going through. the exact same issue. Have you found a solution ? Can you share it please if you did ?

Comment: @Medteck It was year ago, so don't remember, but I had a quick look into the code and I see that I have this serverMiddleware line commented out, which means I simply didn't do it as server middleware if that is of any help.